# Slang for giving the way to do something, not for giving the final thing itself

Tags: american-english, slang

> Someone asks how to grow a chicken, and suddenly some guy just drops a chicken already grown up.

---

> I need to find an algorithm to solve a given problem, but I don't want the code itself, just a way to do it.

---

Considering these scenarios, is there a slang term or phrase not for "giving something already made", but for "giving the way to do it"?

Thanks.

Comment: You want the recipe instead of the meal.

Comment: We also say ""Teaching a man to fish is better than giving him a fish".

Comment: gimme teh codez

Comment: @Robusto hahaha that was good mate!

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!! That was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Actually the expression is "Give a man a fish and he eats for one day, teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime". :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim's comment is a great idiom.  I believe the full original proverb is:

> Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day.  Teach a man to fish, and he will eat for a lifetime.

Another option that is slang but perhaps a bit more useful for many cases:

> I can't figure out how to code this.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Essentially, "point me in the right direction" indicates you want a path to the answer but not the answer itself.

Comment: Jinx!  I commented this at the same time as your answer! :-)